# Open file in an Apache Storm Spout with python

Tags: python, apache-storm

I am trying to make Apache Storm Spout read from a file line by line. I have tried to write these statements, but they didn't work . It gave me the first line only iterated every time:

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):
    # Not much to do here for such a basic spout
    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        ## Open the file with read only permit
        self.f = open('data.txt', 'r')
        ## Read the first line 
        self._conf = conf
        self._context = context
        storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")

    # Process the next tuple
    def nextTuple(self):
        # check if it reach at the EOF to close it 
        for line in self.f.readlines():
            # Emit a random sentence
            storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
            storm.emit([line])

# Start the spout when it's invoked
SimSpout().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** Since I have no way to test this, this answer will simply be from inspection.

You failed to save the filehandle you opened in `initialize()`.  This edit saves the filehandle and then use the saved filehandle for the read.  It also *fixes* (I hope) some indenting that looked wrong.

```
class SimSpout(storm.Spout):
    # Not much to do here for such a basic spout
    def initialize(self, conf, context):
        ## Open the file with read only permit
        self.f = open('mydata.txt', 'r')
        self._conf = conf
        self._context = context

        storm.logInfo("Spout instance starting...")

    # Process the next tuple
    def nextTuple(self):
        # check if it reach at the EOF to close it
        for line in self.f.readlines():
            # Emit a random sentence
            storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
            storm.emit([line])

# Start the spout when it's invoked
SimSpout().run()
```

Comment: Thanks I removed the second question but my code gave me the first line only and the file I have contains alot

Comment: thanks for helping , but i got java.lang.RuntimeException: backtype.storm.multilang.NoOutputException: Pipe to subprocess seems to be broken! No output read.
Serializer Exception:
  File "simspout.py", line 22
    storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: I would carefully check the indenting of the code you put in your editor.  Especially at line 22.

Comment: the problem with this line storm.logInfo("Emiting %s" % line) and storm.emit([line])

Comment: Those lines worked previously.  Thus I would expect the error is a typo or such.